# Python for and if loop count

Tags: python, graphlab

what am I doing wrong here?
Am trying to keep count of of when the value in a column/field of a row/array is less than all the other ones in the row.

So am trying to iterate through each row to check if a particular column is less than the rest of the column.

below code always results to one. So am super confused. Everything I try leads to 1.

```
def is_dog_correct(row, x, y, z, r):
    zero = 0
    for i in xrange(len(row)):
        if row[i-1][x] < row[i-1][y] and row[i-1][z] and row[i-1][r]:
            return Zero + 1
        else:
            return 0
```

Also, could there be an easier way of doing this. Am using graphlab.SFrame

Comment: Possible dupe:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values

Comment: Where is `Zero` defined?  You have `zero` defined, but not `Zero`.

Comment: `return` exits your function immediately, so the loop will only ever run through one iteration.

Comment: Also, due to the way that lists index, if you have a negative value as your index, you will get the last element.  Because `i` starts at 0, `row[i-1]` will evaluate as `row[-1]`, which is the last element in that list.

Comment: I suspect `if row[i-1][x] < row[i-1][y] and row[i-1][z] and row[i-1][r]` isn't what you mean to do. You're checking if `row[i-1][x] < row[i-1][y] ` is true and the value of `row[i-1][z]` is true and the value of `row[i-1][r]` is true.

Comment: Firstly you just shared the code and not the issue/error you are facing. Based on what I see, you initialized `zero = 0` but incrementing `Zero + 1` (with `z` capital)

Comment: Also we do not know what values you are passing to `is_dog_correct(row, x, y, z, r)`. Without these basic information how do you think you would get the best help from SO community? Because we can not guess the actual problem you might be facing

Comment: If the misnaming of `Zero` were really the issue, the code would throw a `NameError`, which it isn't...

Comment: This whole thing really needs a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnGordon: As I mentioned, we do not have the complete information and this is just what I noticed. Maybe he has defined `Zero` somewhere in the outer scope and that is why not getting the exception. But it is for sure he needs `zero` instead of `Zero`

Comment: Perhaps you want `if row[i-1][x] < min(row[i-1][y], row[i-1][z], row[i-1][r])`?  you could write it more verbosely and pick up short-circuiting -- but it's pretty unlikely to make that much of a difference unless this is a really tight loop.

Comment: Thank you guys. return is what was throwing me off.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep counting and return the result after the loop is done.

```
def is_dog_correct(row, x, y, z, r):
    count = 0
    for i in xrange(len(row)):
        if row[i-1][x] < row[i-1][y] and row[i-1][z] and row[i-1][r]:
            count = count + 1
        else:
            pass
    return count
```

Comment: Why to even write the `else` part when it just only does `pass`?

Comment: Of course it is not necessary, however, for a beginner I think it is more clear to leave it there. This is also why I didn't use count += 1

Comment: No, it is not clear to use `pass`. And specially not to beginner. If you do, you are not a good mentor, because you taught him the wrong way to do thing at the first place. Using `count += 1` is also perfectly fine. If the OP do not know, he will get to know something new. Also, SO is not just for one user. Your answer will act as a reference for other users looking at this issue in the future. So, it should also take that as well into the consideration :)

Comment: Thank you a.smiet. Figured out what the problem was prior to checking. I should have gotten an email, that the question has been answered to avoid 30 mins of brain freezes. So I could use count+=1 to replace the count = count +1? also I do not need the else as well?

Comment: Yes, `count += 1` is basically the short way for `count = count +1`. You don't need the else statement in this case, the `pass` statement just does nothing. @Moinuddin Quadri: If it is not clear to you to use `pass`, maybe it is clear for others, like in my case. People think in different ways and SO is not for mentoring someone but to answer specific questions. Moreover, to say it in your words: If the OP doesn't get the `pass` statement, he will get to know something new.